# Python strptime with variable text

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have a list of dates as strings. It looks like this:

```
[
  "January 29-30 Meeting - 2013",
  "March 19-20 Meeting - 2013",
  "April/May 30-1 Meeting - 2013",
  "June 18-19 Meeting - 2013",
  "July 30-31 Meeting - 2013",
  "September 17-18 Meeting - 2013",
  "October 29-30 Meeting - 2013",
  "December 17-18 Meeting - 2013"
]
```

I need to parse these dates to `datetime` format.

```
datetime.strptime("January 29-30 Meeting - 2013", "%B %d-[something] - %Y")
datetime.strptime("January 29-30 Meeting - 2013", "%B [something]-%d [something] - %Y")
```

Is there any way I can tell strptime, in the format specifier, to ignore the text in `[something]` since it can be variable? Is there a format specifier for variable text?

Comment: I assume it's going to be regex and out of my field, but what of `"April/May 30-1"`?

Comment: You're right. I think I'll manage these exceptions manually... what a pain. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `_strptime.TimeRE` object with an additional directive that lazily matches any sequence of characters:

```
from datetime import datetime
import _strptime
TimeRE = _strptime.TimeRE()
TimeRE.update({'x': '.*?'})
_strptime._TimeRE_cache = TimeRE
print(datetime.strptime("January 29-30 Meeting - 2013", "%B %d-%x - %Y"))
```

This outputs:

```
2013-01-29 00:00:00
```

Comment: I think your answer is interesting, but not really a recommended way to go about it, since it changes the behaviour globally and could have very unexpected side effects for a larger script. I certainly would not call it Pythonic.

Answer (score 3):

There is no wildcard directive for `strptime`. You can see a list of the directives here https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime

A sensible way to solve your problem would be to combine a regex with the `strptime`. I.e. filter out the text with the regex and put the remaining, restricted text into the `strptime`, or by just passing the matched groups directly into `datetime`.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

ss = [
  "January 29-30 Meeting - 2013",
  "March 19-20 Meeting - 2013",
  "April/May 30-1 Meeting - 2013",
  "June 18-19 Meeting - 2013",
  "July 30-31 Meeting - 2013",
  "September 17-18 Meeting - 2013",
  "October 29-30 Meeting - 2013",
  "December 17-18 Meeting - 2013"
]

FORMAT = '%B %d %Y'

for s in ss:
    match = re.search(r"(\w+)\s(\d+)-(\d+)\s.*\s(\d{4})", s)
    if match:
        dt1 = datetime.strptime(f'{match.group(1)} {match.group(2)} {match.group(4)}', FORMAT)
        dt2 = datetime.strptime(f'{match.group(1)} {match.group(3)} {match.group(4)}', FORMAT)

        print (dt1, dt2)
```

Note that you also have the `April/May 30-1` complication in there, I'm not addressing that, since you are not asking about that.

As a bonus though:

```
for s in ss:
    match = re.search(r"((\w+)/)?(\w+)\s(\d+)-(\d+)\s.*\s(\d{4})", s)
    if match:
        dt1 = datetime.strptime(
            f'{match.group(2) if match.group(2) else match.group(3)} {match.group(4)} {match.group(6)}', FORMAT)
        dt2 = datetime.strptime(
            f'{match.group(3)} {match.group(5)} {match.group(6)}', FORMAT)

        print (dt1, dt2)
```

Also, note the interesting, if a bit hacky solution offered by @blhsing below, involving `_strptime.TimeRE`. I would not recommend doing anything like that, but it is interesting to know you could actually change the behaviour of `strptime` itself that way.

Comment: Note that this is using `search` instead of `match` to make the first example work - the second example actually matches the entire string from the start, so you could consider using `match` instead.